# android layout: how to write this one?

Tags: android

I want an activity with below layout:

```
top button
middle(scroll view)
bottom button
```

I want the bottom button to attach to the bottom of the activity view, and the middle part occupies the rest of the space.

How I can write the layout xml file?

Below doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="0px" />

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lines="1" android:hint="发微博内容" android:layout_weight="0.9" />
            <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/search_btn"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"></Button>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:paddingTop="5dip" />
        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lv01" android:layout_height="390dp">
        </ListView>
        <Button android:id="@+id/create_new_btn" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="我要评论" android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that case, just take a **RelativeLayout**, its better for this case and you don't need to take any sub-layout.

Just try this once and post your XML layout here for the further improvement.

From your xml layout code, i can assume, you just want to have:

EditText+Button=>Top,
TextView+ListView=>Middle,
Create New button=>Bottom,

is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Button" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Button" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></Button>
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_below="@+id/button1" android:layout_above="@+id/button2">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>        
</RelativeLayout>
```

I think something like that would work.  The important part in that layout is the `android:layout_below` and `android:layout_above`.  You can replace the `ScrollView` with other layouts such as `ListView` and it will remain below the first button and above the second regardless of how big it gets.  Likewise, the buttons have the attributes `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` which will keep them to the top and the bottom of the RelativeView respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, go with LinearLayout, and play with the weights:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0">
  </Button>
  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <!-- Stuff in scroll view -->
  </ScrollView>  
  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0">
  </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

@ParashMayani is right..

Here is the implementation :

```
<LinearLayout android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/relLayout" android:orientation="horizontal"  >



        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1" android:hint="Hello" android:layout_weight="0.7"/>

            <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Search"
             android:layout_weight="0.3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/search_btn" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:paddingTop="5dip" android:layout_below="@id/relLayout"/>

      <Button android:id="@+id/create_new_btn" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="我要评论" android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lv01" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_above="@id/create_new_btn" android:layout_below="@id/TextView01" />
```